# Printing a diamond-shaped figure

Tags: java, unit-testing, formatting, junit

How can I optimize this code to have fewer loops and return values for unit testing?

```
 public class Diamond {

public void DiamondShape(int num) {

   for(int ucount=num;ucount>0;ucount--) {
//Loop to print blank space
    for(int count_sp=1;count_sp<ucount;count_sp++)
        System.out.printf(" ");
//Loop to print *
    for(int count_ast=num;count_ast>=ucount;count_ast--)
        System.out.printf("* ");
    System.out.println();
   }

//Loop for lower half
  for(int lcount=1;lcount<num;lcount++) {
    //Loop to print blank space
    for(int count_sp=0;count_sp<lcount;count_sp++)
            System.out.printf(" ");
    //Loop to print *
        for(int count_ast=num-1;count_ast>=lcount;count_ast--)
            System.out.printf("* ");
    System.out.println();
    }
  } 
}
```

Output when `num` = 3:

> ```
>    *
>   * *
>  * * *
>   * *
>    *
> ```

This is how the output should be. `num` indicates the star in center line.

Answer (score 5):

First of all: Use a StringBuilder instead of System.out.println so you can easily compare the result of your method with an expected output.

Your test could look like: (I renamed you method to draw and moved the size to the instance.)

```
@Test
public void test4()
{
    StringBuilder expected = new StringBuilder();
    expected.append( "   * \n" );
    expected.append( "  * * \n" );
    expected.append( " * * * \n" );
    expected.append( "* * * * \n" );
    expected.append( " * * * \n" );
    expected.append( "  * * \n" );
    expected.append( "   * \n" );
    assertEquals( expected.toString(), new Diamond( 4 ).draw() );
}
```

After you have all your tests (I have just created some for 0-4) you can try to extract some methods with duplicate code.

```
public class Diamond
{
    private int size;

    public Diamond( int size )
    {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String draw()
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for( int ucount = size; ucount > 0; ucount-- )
        {
            appendSpaces( result, ucount - 1 );
            appendStars( result, size - ucount + 1 );
            newLine( result );
        }

        for( int lcount = 1; lcount < size; lcount++ )
        {
            appendSpaces( result, lcount );
            appendStars( result, size - lcount );
            newLine( result );
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private void newLine( StringBuilder result ) // just for better readability
    {
        result.append( "\n" );
    }

    private void appendStars( StringBuilder result, int count ) // just for better readability
    {
        repeat( result, "* ", count );
    }

    private void appendSpaces( StringBuilder result, int count ) // just for better readability
    {
        repeat( result, " ", count );
    }

    private void repeat( StringBuilder result, String string, int count )
    {
        for( int c = 0; c < count; c++ )
            result.append( string );
    }
}
```

If you want to get rid of one of the loops you could even merge it to:

```
public String draw()
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for( int ucount = size; ucount >= -size; ucount-- )
    {
        boolean isMiddleRows = ucount == 0 || ucount == -1;
        if( isMiddleRows ) continue;
        appendSpaces( result, Math.abs( ucount ) - 1 );
        appendStars( result, size - Math.abs( ucount ) + 1 );
        newLine( result );
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

It's pretty cool to have enough tests do try such refactoring :)

Comment: What other tests can we perform in this program

Comment: I think checking the output for 0 to 4 is enough. Maybe you can test negative values, but in general you just need to find all border cases. -1, 0, 1, odd(3), even(4), maybe some larger number too.

Comment: I am raising an exception if value is negative or a string so can we create a test case for the exception that I am raising

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083161/junit-exception-testing

Comment: how can i test methods appendStars() appendSpaces() and repeat()

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/25254/21181

Comment: I wouldn't test the append methods. As soon as the repeat is tested or used from a library the other method are trivial forwards to this method and test are useless.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unit test the `System.out` output, you can set the `PrintStream` of `System.out` by using the `setOut` method.

```
private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

@Before
public void setUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
}

@After
public void cleanUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(null);
}

@Test
public void testOut() {
    System.out.println("hello");
    System.out.println("hi");
    String[] linesOfOutput = outContent.toString().split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    assertEquals("hello", linesOfOutput[0]);
    assertEquals("hi", linesOfOutput[1]);
}
```

Of course, it would be better to pass an `OutputStream` as parameter to the method and write to that.

```
public void writeDiamondShape ( int num, OutputStream outputStream ) {
    ...
}
```

As for optimization

```
public static void writeDiamond(int num){
    int loops = num * 2 - 1;
    int stars = 1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < loops; i++ ) {

        // Print spaces
        int spaces = Math.abs(num - i - 1);
        for ( int j = 0; j < spaces; j++ ) {
            System.out.print ( " " );
        }

        // Print stars
        for ( int j = 0; j < stars; j++ ) {
            System.out.print ( "* " );
        }
        System.out.println();

        // Increment / Decrement stars to print next time
        stars += (i+1 < num) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should definitely go with the parameter solution if you don't want to use a string return. Changing in, err and out might lead do unexpected behavior, e.g. if you debug a failing test by System.out.print().